# Writing a custom selector plugin

Tags: jquery

Now I am learning how to write  a custom selector plugin in "Learning Jquery 4th edition". I don't understand this code snippet,  so i need you help to make it clear to me?

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        group: function(element, index, matches, set) {
            var num = parseInt(matches[3], 10);
            if (isNaN(num)) {
                 return false;
            }
            return index % (num * 2) <num;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `$.expr[':']` is the part that is making you confused about this code , then you should first learn about `$.expr` which is used to extending the sizzle selectors see docs https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#sizzleselectorscreatepseudofunction

Comment: Which statements are confusing you?